# Rest API Pagination Using ADF

Tags: pagination, azure-data-factory

I am struggling with a rest API and getting all the records using Azure Data Factory, I am only getting the first record, however in Postman I get them all can someone help me with pagination ? Below is my output from postman which has the headers showing how many pages etc, I cant figure out what method to use in ADF ?

[Postman Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whExI.png)

I have tried AbsoluteUrl Value Headers $.paging.next this didnt work :(

Comment: can you add sample url

Comment: Hi Pratik, I am using this URL 

https://api.ace360connect.org/connect-api/beta/apprentices

I guess I need to add something to this ?